# How to create a custom "Shapes" menu in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint, ribbon, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

By the "Shapes Menu," I mean the menu that you get to from the ribbon by going to Home -> Shapes.

I would like to either:

1. Choose my own shapes for within the Shapes menu, including changing the names of separators
2. Create my own ribbon menu from scratch that allows you to create a gallery with separators

Here is an image of the menu I want:

[image]

Note: I'm interested in doing this for Powerpoint 2013, though I don't think that makes a difference.

Comment: Research in google "custom ribbon".  You will need to create an XML file and insert it into the PPT file.  You will also need to write VBA code to interact with buttons created in the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not possible to create your custom shape in the powerpoint You are using they are not so helpful you can use the one which are given in the option the are not so bad.